# Unable to install Hypertrack's Pod

Tags: ios, cocoapods, hypertrack

I am integrating `Hypertrack SDK` in my iOS app and have followed steps from their documentation. According to their docs following is the code that needs to be added in the `podfile`:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'AppName' do
pod 'HyperTrack'

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.3'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I run `pod install` command in terminal, it does not install the hypertrack pod. I even tried `pod update` but it is not working.

Can anyone help me and explain me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Hypertrack's Support Team on Slack and was able to fix this issue. Following are the steps that I followed :-

1. Updated Pod Repo - `pod repo update`
2. Removed hypertrack's pod code and performed pod update (According to the support team this is done to remove any older version, if any) - `pod install`
3. After that I added hypertrack's pod code again and performed pod update again - `pod update` and voila it worked!

I am not sure why I was unable to install it when I tried before but after performing these steps I was able to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did the log return anything? Try updating your cocoapods, this might work.

Comment: no there was no error whatsoever. I updated cocoapods and tried but still it didn't work